# trim JS object to remove extra params with curly braces

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an object response here

```
result.joblist = {
  "collection_job_status_list": [
    {
      "application_context": {
        "application_id": "a4",
        "context_id": "c4"
      },
      "creation_time": "15699018476102",
      "progress": 100,
      "status": "READY",
      "phase": "ACTIVE",
      "job_error": {}
    },
    {
      "application_context": {
        "application_id": "a6",
        "context_id": "c6"
      },
      "creation_time": "15698648632523",
      "progress": 100,
      "status": "READY",
      "phase": "ACTIVE",
      "job_error": {}
    }
  ],
  "result": {
    "request_result": "ACCEPTED",
    "error": {}
  }
}
```

Need to get rid of `{"application_context": & ending }` here, just need `application_id":"a4","context_id":"c4"` at the same level.

I have tried something like this, but not able to move ahead.

```
var newObj: any = {};
if (allJobs && allJobs.length > 0) {
  // this.rowData = this.allJobs;
  // this.allJobs = this.allJobs['application_id'];
  //let ele:object = allJobs.application_context;
  allJobs.forEach(ele => {
    newObj = {
      application_id: ele.application_context.application_id,
      context_id: ele.application_context.application_context
    };
    return newObj;
  });
}
```

Comment: var newObj:any = {};
        if (allJobs && allJobs.length > 0 ) {
        // this.rowData = this.allJobs;
        // this.allJobs = this.allJobs['application_id'];
        //let ele:object = allJobs.application_context;
            allJobs.forEach(ele => {
            newObj = 
    {"application_id":ele.application_context.application_id,
                            
    "context_id":ele.application_context.application_context}
           return newObj;
  });
}

Comment: What is your expected output, can you please update in question? Do we need to remove application_context property from the object and those inner properties want to be in root object?

Comment: Yes, want to keep others as same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` and `destructuring`

- Get the `collection_job_status_list` from result
- Loop over the values take out the required values from `application_context` key and merge with remaining values
- Build the same structure as original result

```js
let result = {"collection_job_status_list": [{"application_context": {"application_id": "a4","context_id": "c4"},"creation_time": "15699018476102","progress": 100,"status": "READY","phase": "ACTIVE","job_error": {}},{"application_context": {"application_id": "a6","context_id": "c6"},"creation_time": "15698648632523","progress": 100,"status": "READY","phase": "ACTIVE","job_error": {}}],"result": {"request_result": "ACCEPTED","error": {}}}

let { collection_job_status_list, ...rest } = result

let modified = collection_job_status_list.map(({
  application_context: {
    application_id,
    context_id
  },
  ...rest
}) => ({ ...rest, context_id, application_id}))

let final = {
  collection_job_status_list: modified,
  ...rest
}

console.log(final)
```

Comment: @Gaurav always happy to help :), [`what should i do when someone answers my question`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `map` function

```js
const result = {};
result.joblist = {
  "collection_job_status_list": [
    {
      "application_context": {
        "application_id": "a4",
        "context_id": "c4"
      },
      "creation_time": "15699018476102",
      "progress": 100,
      "status": "READY",
      "phase": "ACTIVE",
      "job_error": {}
    },
    {
      "application_context": {
        "application_id": "a6",
        "context_id": "c6"
      },
      "creation_time": "15698648632523",
      "progress": 100,
      "status": "READY",
      "phase": "ACTIVE",
      "job_error": {}
    }
  ],
  "result": {
    "request_result": "ACCEPTED",
    "error": {}
  }
}


result.joblist.collection_job_status_list = result.joblist.collection_job_status_list.map(item => {
  return {
     "application_id": item.application_context.application_id,
     "context_id": item.application_context.context_id
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Or you can use `map` function along with shorthand es6 syntaxes

```js
const result = {};
result.joblist = {
  "collection_job_status_list": [
    {
      "application_context": {
        "application_id": "a4",
        "context_id": "c4"
      },
      "creation_time": "15699018476102",
      "progress": 100,
      "status": "READY",
      "phase": "ACTIVE",
      "job_error": {}
    },
    {
      "application_context": {
        "application_id": "a6",
        "context_id": "c6"
      },
      "creation_time": "15698648632523",
      "progress": 100,
      "status": "READY",
      "phase": "ACTIVE",
      "job_error": {}
    }
  ],
  "result": {
    "request_result": "ACCEPTED",
    "error": {}
  }
}


result.joblist.collection_job_status_list = result.joblist.collection_job_status_list.map(({application_context}) => {
  return {
     ...application_context
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

EDIT:

The things you want to keep in your array depends on what you are returning from the `map`. You return the keys you want to keep. So if you want other items.

If you have an array A

```
A = [
  {
    nest: {
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
    },
    key1: 5,
    key2: 7,
  },
  {
    nest: {
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
    },
    key1: 5,
    key2: 7,
  },
  {
    nest: {
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
    },
    key1: 5,
    key2: 7,
  }
]
```

Let us assume you want `x` from `nest`, `key1` and `key2` in your final output. You will then do

```
const finalOutput = A.map(item => {
  return {
     x: item.nest.x, // x from nest
     key1: item.key1, // key1
     key2: item.key2,  // key2
  }
})
```

But there are shorthand forms for doing this. Let's assume that the `item` we get in our `map function` is already divided into a `nest` and a `rest` variable. The `nest` contains `item.nest` and the `rest` is `{key1: 5,key2:7}`, then you can simply return `x` from `nest` and everything else from `rest`

```
const finalOutput = A.map(({nest, ...rest}) => {
  return {
     x: nest.x, // x from nest
     ...rest, // everything else
  }
})
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks! How do I keep the other items as it is (like other items at the same level) along with  ...application_context

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is a map. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Try modifying the code as below and you should have your expected output.

```
var newObj: any = {};
var newArray;
if (allJobs && allJobs.length > 0) {
  newArray = allJobs.map(ele => {
    newObj = {
      application_id: ele.application_context.application_id,
      context_id: ele.application_context.application_context
    };
    return newObj;
  });
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey thanks, would be good to a avoid using new variables or have the result stored in new object.